# Creating windows form application to run web project code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I am working on creating windows form application in c#. 
I have a web application. I want to write a windows form application where I provide all the input details required for the web app.

I am completely new to windows Form applications.

Basically I want to add three three text boxes, read the data from it and run the code in the web app.

In a nutshell, I want to make the web application run as a windows form application.

Can any one share some ideas on it.

That would be very helpfull.

Thank you.

Comment: Please make your question clear.

Comment: I have created a web application in c# which accepts some paths as input.   I want to convert this application as Windows Form application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your summary, "In a nutshell, I want to make the web application run as a windows form application."  I assume you want the ability to run your web application inside of a Windows Forms application.  Something like this has its many uses, especially in intranet applications.

All you need to do is:

1. Drag a WebBrowser control onto your Windows Forms application.
2. In the Events tab of the Properties window, add a new event handler to the Load event.
3. In the code behind of your Form, simply call the Navigate() method to your site.

   ```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       webBrowser1.Navigate("http://blahhhhhh");
   }
   ```

Comment: I have created a web application in c# which accepts some paths as input.   I want to convert this application as Windows Form application. Will this be okay if i use the http path as address of site when i run the application from Visual studio.